# Will BoxedApp work in C# or VB6?

Tags: c#, vb6

I use BoxedApp for emulating a file system and a system registry. I know that it is used in Delphi and C++. Is it used in C# and VB6?

Comment: it certainly is used in several languages... but what is your question ?

Comment: Voted to close for asking a "yes/no" question.  Such questions are not a good fit with stack overflow.  This site is not ideal for "Yes/No" answers.  There should be some technical answer beyond a boolean True/False.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is used in C# and VB6:

From here: [BoxedApp SDK](http://www.boxedapp.com/boxedappsdk/)

> BoxedApp SDK is available in the following forms:
>
> 1. DLL - for all environments: VC++, **VB6, C#**, VB.Net, Delphi / Builder C++ and so on;
> 2. Static library (full version only) - for all VC++ versions;
> 3. OBJ file (for static linking) - for all Delphi / Builder C++ versions;

Comment: Thank you. I was not attentive.